# add class to woocommerce single product template gallery thumbnails if media attachment ACF field toggled (true/false)

Tags: php, functions, advanced-custom-fields

i have the following custom field (quick_ship):
[image]
[image]
[image]

i've added this in functions but not working at the moment:

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('quick_ship');
    $size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size, array ('class' => 'quick-ship' ) );
    }
```